# Get indexpath item of UITableview in ios5

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I have seen this topic before ,I know iOS5 has another way to do that, but I couldn't find it.

If I using this function in iOS5.

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

I get a crash when trying to `NSLog` the `indexPath.item`. The some problem with `.item`.
How I have to replace that to fit iOS5 and also iOS6?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`item` is a property added for `UICollectionViews` in iOS 6, a `UITableView` index path uses the `row` property. use `indexPath.row` instead

Comment: thanks ! and how can i check if its ios5 or 6 to know when should i use row or item ?

Comment: use row for tableviews (because it only has rows) and items for collection views (because it can have rows and columns, items makes more sense)

Comment: still dont get you. i am using the method i wrote in my question in ios5 and 6 to populate it . within this method , how can i know if to use item or row -for ios5 /6 ?

Comment: item is for collection views only. you are using a table view, not a collection view, so use row for all iOS versions